# Efficient SQL query to return parents that satisfy constraints on children

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, query-performance

I've got a schema something like having an `Entity` table, with a to-many relationship to `Attribute`, which has a to-many relationship to `Value`. `Attribute` has a column `Name`, and `Value` has a column `Value`:

```
Entity
------
Id
Name


Attribute
---------
Id
EntityId
Name


Value
-----
Id
AttributeId
Value
```

I need to be able to construct a query that will return only `Entity` rows that have certain combinations of attribute/value children. Currently I'm writing the query something like:

```
select
    *
    from Entity e   
    where exists(
        select * from Attribute a 
            join Value v on v.AttributeId = a.id 
            where a.EntityId = e.id and a.Name = 'color' and v.Value = 'red')
    and exists(
        select * from Attribute a 
            join Value v on v.AttributeId = a.id 
            where a.EntityId = e.id and a.Name = 'size' and v.Value = 'small')
```

This works, but every extra attribute filter adds another `exists` clause, and I'm nervous about performance. Is there a more efficient way to write queries of this type, or is it likely to be perfectly performant if I use correct indexes etc?

Comment: Could you add some sample data? Also is the same row likely to satisfy both conditions as above?

Comment: Is this a new system? Is it too late to get rid of these tables and replace them with a proper relational model?

Comment: @Colin'tHart The rest of the db is a normal relational model, this part however needs to be flexible and query against entities that have varying numbers of free-form properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to predict if your original query will have performance problems. We don't know how large your tables are, what indexes you have, how many filters you might add, how quickly the queries need to finish, or so on. You may want to consider writing the query in the most natural way to do and measuring performance. If performance is acceptable leave the code as is.

If you do need to improve performance, you can consider a rewrite similar to the following:

```
select *
from Entity e 
WHERE e.id IN (
    SELECT a.id
    FROM Attribute a 
    join [Value] v on v.AttributeId = a.id 
    WHERE a.Name IN ('color', 'size') AND v.Value IN ('red', 'small') -- redundant filter to improve performance
    GROUP BY a.id
    HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN a.Name = 'color' and v.Value = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
    AND MAX(CASE WHEN a.Name = 'size' and v.Value = 'small' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
);
```

That will give you a single scan of the `attribute` and `value` tables regardless of how many filters you add to the `HAVING` clause. One downside is that you're likely to get a poor cardinality estimate from the `HAVING` filter, but if the goal of the filters is to filter out most of the rows from the `Entity` table then that may not be a problem.

Comment: The table would rarely have many rows - the current use case is <10, although future uses might have a few hundred, tops. The question was more about whether there's an established pattern for this sort of query, as it seems like a common problem to want to solve, and expressing it with sql doesn't seem straightforward.

Comment: It is a common problem. It's called relational division. See this question and answer at SO: **[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)** for a lot (more than 10) ways to rewrite. The performance tests there are for Postgres, not SQL Server, but you'll get a good insight. It may be surprising but - depending on distribution of values, size of tables, etc. - the multiple EXISTS subqueries is often more efficient than the GROUP BY / HAVING method.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like that:

```
SELECT e.Id, count(1) AS cnt
  FROM Entity    AS e
  JOIN Attribute AS a ON a.EntityID = e.Id
  JOIN Value     AS v ON v.AttributeId = a.Id
 WHERE (a.Name = 'color' AND v.Value = 'red')
    OR (a.Name = 'size'  AND v.Value = 'small')
--  OR ( ... ) -- extended here
 GROUP BY e.Id
HAVING cnt = 2 -- exact number of desired attributes
;
```